# Java Type Conversion: Where is the conversion actually?

Tags: java, types, reference

I am asking myself this:

Why does Java call it type conversion if - in some contexts - the type does not change at all?

Let's look at a simple example:

String s = "a";

Object o = s;

This works just fine, because it is a widening reference conversion. However, nothing is ever CONVERTED in this context. When compiling the 2nd assignment statement, the compiler sees that the right expression is of another type than the left one. But this does not imply a compiling error, since Object is a supertype of String. Therefore, the reference stored in s is allowed to be stored in o. So, actually, no type is being converted here.

Or is this wrong?

Comment: You are correct, what happens here is an (implicit) cast from `String` to `Object`. It is not a type conversion.

Comment: Ok, yes, thanks. Nevertheless, nothing is actually casted, right? The reference value is unchanged, since it does not contain any type. So, basically, we just have 2 variables referencing the same object, with only the types of the variables being different. I don't see what's casted here.

Comment: `String` is casted to `Object`. The compiler implicitely adds a cast like `Object o = (Object) s;`. Despite that, `o` and `s` are still referencing the same object.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I cannot find it in the JLS. Also, uncompiling the above does not reveal this. If this really would be the case, then there would be a conversion, since the casting expression's value is of type Object, whereas the type of expression being the operand is of type String.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html Actually Oracle does call it a conversion, even though the referenced object is still the same: "A conversion from type Thread to type Object requires no run-time action; Thread is a subclass of Object, so any reference produced by an expression of type Thread is a valid reference value of type Object."

Comment: Well, I think I will stick with it as follows:
I assume that the compiler will add the casting expression you have outlined - (Object) s - during compilation. Then, using the word conversion makes sense for me, since we now have an expression of type Object, whereas the base expression was of type String. Both experessions have the same value though.

Also, when executing the statement at runtime, there is no need for a type check with respect to the object's type, since Object is a supertype of String.

Would you say that this is correct? Thanks for your effort here :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is worth remembering that `s` is a *reference* to a `String`, not a String.

When you assign the reference to an `Object` reference, the type of reference changes, but the reference and the object referenced is untouched.

There is no actual operation to do this as no data is altered. This only alters how the compiler checks its value. Note: the real CPU doesn't have any checks to perform at runtime. To the CPU, it is just the address of the object.

c.f. for primitives, assigning to a different type alters the data.

Comment: Hi Peter.
I dont think it is correct that "the type of reference" changes. The reference itself does not change at all; it remains the same 64-bit pattern as before. The type of the reference is always a class wrt to the definition of reference types in the JLS.

Comment: @chipsmonster91 The reference is type checked at runtime to make sure the byte code is valid and the different local variables have different types.